# Testing django redirects

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am noticing while trying to test redirects on a page that requires login I get this this outcome

: Response redirected to '/profiles/login/?redirect_to=%2Fprofiles%2F1%2F', expected '/profiles/login/'Expected '/profiles/login/?redirect_to=%2Fprofiles%2F1%2F' to equal '/profiles/login/'.

This is the test that I wrote for it:

```
class ProfileDetailView(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
                self.client = Client()
                create_user()

    def test_profile_detail_for_redirect_if_no_authentication(self):
        user = User.objects.get(email="youcantseeme@example.com")
        profile_detail_response = self.client.get(f'/profiles/{user.id}/', follow=True)
        self.assertRedirects(profile_detail_response, '/profiles/login/', status_code=302, target_status_code=200)
```

I'm using a login mixin for the generic details page

```
class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profiles/detail.html'
    login_url = '/profiles/login'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

    def get_queryset(self):
            """
            TODO Determine criteria for filtering
            """
            return Profile.objects
```

I've been trying to find a way to check that the redirect was successful and went to the right page but the matcher for redirects doesn't seem right, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
in settings.py you have to set `LOGIN_URL = '/profiles/login/'`

Comment: It changed to this Response redirected to '/profiles/login/?next=/profiles/1/', expected '/profiles/login/'Expected '/profiles/login/?next=/profiles/1/' to equal '/profiles/login/'.
 Do I need to do something to ignore the ?next=/profiles/1/ part?